# How to add features in lingpipe classifier?

Tags: java, machine-learning, lingpipe

Now I'm just training a DynamicLMClassifier on a data set and classifying my text into categories. How do I add a feature so that the classifier gives certain words more weight, eg, if this sentence contains "professional", it is very probably in Category A?
Or how to classify based on paragraphs instead of ngrams?

I notice there is a featureextractor but that doesn't seem to take in arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as a comment but I don't have the privilege yet.

The DynamicLMClassifier is does not allow for arbitrary features. One that does is our LogisticRegression classifier but it is more complex to use. A good place to start is the tutorial at:

http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/logistic-regression/read-me.html

Your second question of how to classify based on paragraphs instead of ngrams is a bit unclear. Using entire paragraphs as a single feature will likely create very sparse data.

Breck

Comment: Answers that link to offsite resources aren't great because they break if the links break... If you can include some information in your answer that would be better. If you are simply recommending a tutorial then that is probably better suited as a comment.